# I am making a ring network where each node can only talk to its peers using socket in python

Tags: python, sockets, blocking, recv

The way I am trying to implement is that each process opens 2 sockets, one to listen to its right node and other to send connect to its left node. This way I can get the whole ring connected using sockets but the problem is that when a peer try to receive a message from left node (to which connect was sent) in while(1), it keeps on reading 0 bites without blocking and disconnects the socket after some try's. How do I make the recv wait for the message from its left peer.

Comment: You have to rethink what HANDSHAKE is supposed to do. You call `client.recv` in `recieve_message_anti_clockwise` if HANDSHAKE, but HANDSHAKE says nothing about whether `client` is connected, and of course it's an error to call `recv` for an unconnected `client`. Why do you have `client.connect` and `client.recv` in two separate thread functions at all, rather than only one function combining `handshake_message` and `recieve_message_anti_clockwise`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I am trying to achieve is that , creating a ring in which each peer can connect only to its left and right side node. Each node opens 2 sockets, one listens to the right hand node and other connects to the left hand node. HANDSHAKE connects to the left hand node, so if each node in the ring does HANDSHAKE (connects to left node), a ring with all peers get created.

Comment: After that I am trying to create a message on any node and try to send it in clockwise and anti-clockwise direction. But the code does not block on client.recv in recieve_message_anti_clockwise and continuously runs in the loop after HANDSHAKE(successful connection).

Comment: 1. You didn't respond to my information that HANDSHAKE is not suitable to enable the calling of `client.recv` (since it only reflects the `conn` and not the `client` connection), did you? This is an error which must be corrected. 2. By writing `After that`, you suggest that the complete ring would be connected before the first message is sent, but that's not true; there's no synchronisation which would prevent a peer from sending a message to its neighbor before that has connected to the opposite neighbor.

Comment: Thanks much for your valuable feedback. I understand what you are saying, HANDSHAKE does not ensure that the client is connected, let me try to accommodate the changes you suggested.